# curl command for asynchronous requests with Google Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

Now that the Google Speech API is no longer in beta, my curl command needs to be updated, but the docs for speech: longrunningrecognize bring up a 404. I need to make an asynchronous request because my file is longer than one minute. Previously, I used this:

```
     curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" \-H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" \POST https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:asyncrecognize \-d @sync-request.json
```

and now wanted to substitute

```
    curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" \-H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" \POST https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize \-d @sync-request.json
```

but I get the error message: Error 404 (Not Found)!!1

What is the proper curl command I should be using now?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this! This format has been working for me.

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTHORIZATIONKEY" \
 https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize \
  -d @sync-request.json
```